# Building a linux service in Ruby that other processes can interact with, maybe via a socket?

Tags: ruby, linux, api, sockets

I'm looking into building a service to run in the background that allows clients to connect and send commands, and get data back. I'm planning on writing the service in Ruby (as a gem) but wanted to know what the best method would be to allow clients to connect to the API?

I figured a socket connection would make sense, like you'd connect with Redis or something, but I'm not sure where to start!

Any tips would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

Yep, you're on the right path. A socket is just a bidirectional communication channel that allows two programs to exchange bytes. If both endpoints are on the same machine, UNIX sockets are the obvious choice; otherwise, you'll need a TCP socket to communicate over the network. The principle is the same in either case.

On top of the socket, you'll have to define your own protocol, or you could use an existing one (such as HTTP) if it applies to your situation.

[A random sockets tutorial.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_socket_programming.htm)

Comment: The basic idea is the service will generate IDs for the client, thats pretty much it. There is some stuff that the service needs to do to handle unique IDs etc, but in terms of the communication layer, a request for an ID (and maybe to get some STATUS info) and to get some data back, its pretty simple. A bit like how redis's communication works.

Answer (score 2):

Since you ask for any tips, my advice to you is that building a service container is hard work.  Since you don't actually need to, there being lots of awesome service containers already, you should probably use one of those.

I would recommend something behind HTTP, which gives you a whole lot of advantages around existing tooling, message framing, content negotiation, scaling your service, and deployment and upgrade models.

If you want to avoid external dependencies, using something like Webrick or Mongel that is pure Ruby is a fine way to avoid needing to wrap Apache or Nginx around your system.

This also allows you to separate out the concerns in your project: work on building the actual service layer first, handling commands and returning responses.  Run that under any web server, and get it going.

Then when you have time, focus separately on how to build the service container to meet your needs: because you know that the underlying service layer works fine, you can focus on only solving the container problems.

If you really do want to build your own container, I strongly recommend you use something higher level than a socket.  Tools like [0mq](http://www.zeromq.org/) provide framing and other message layer features that you don't get from a socket, and make it much easier to focus on defining the interesting parts of your problem space - the commands - rather than low level details like parsing a wire format and protocol.

Comment: The basic concept of the system is, the service will generate incremental and unique IDs (across a sharded system) for the web application to use on request. I need it to be as fast as possible so HTTP seems like overkill since the client will *always* be on the same machine.

Comment: That would have been useful to add to the question. :)  You should just use snowflake: https://github.com/twitter/snowflake

Comment: I've been chatting with the guys there, and at boundry/flake - however, I use the IDs for short URLS so for me (besides uniqueness) the IDs need to be small, and grow over time. Snowflakes will always fit into 64bit (or flake, 128bit) and will always be long numbers. Thats not what I want. :(

Comment: I've come up with a solution, whereby the service will allocate a range of IDs (say, 1000) over a time period, the time period is used as salt, along with part of the IP address or something unique to that node. I'm not 100% sure on the exact values i'll use yet, but thats the idea.

Comment: Reference: https://github.com/twitter/snowflake/issues/7 https://github.com/boundary/flake/issues/3

Comment: Ultimately, my advice stands then: use an existing container, probably HTTP.  Just amortize the cost of ID allocation appropriately. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a Ruby/Rails app with Redis running in the background on an EC2 server (Amazon Web Services AWS). This is the ubuntu build I found to be easiest to work with:

```
Linux version 2.6.32-341-ec2 (buildd@crested) (gcc version 4.4.3 (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5) ) #42-Ubuntu SMP Tue Dec 6 14:56:13 UTC 2011
```

In my main .rb file that does most of the polling/searching I have this rubygems required, you should definitely check them out:

```
require 'aws'
require 'redis'
require 'timeout'
require 'json'
```

Let me know what you are specifically trying to do if that doesn't help you enough. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! Though the idea is the service doesn't do much until a client connects and asks for some data.

Answer (score 0):

I've built a couple of daemons with [EventMachine](http://rubyeventmachine.com/) in the past. It is efficient and powerful, supports TCP, HTTP and everything else. People even write [web servers](http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/) on top of it.